# How can I decorate the REST response in Spring (Boot)?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-boot

I've got a Spring Boot application that returns various objects that get encoded as JSON responses and I'd like to post-process them and add information to certain super classes.

Is there a way to filter, intercept, etc. the object responses from my REST endpoints before they get encoded to JSON with Jackson.

A filter won't work since it operates at the `HttpServlet{Request,Response}` level.

Comment: what about a Controller Advice?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I guess `ResponseBodyAdvice` is your friend. Basically it:

> Allows customizing the response after the execution of an
>   `@ResponseBody` or a `ResponseEntity` controller method but before the
>   body is written with an `HttpMessageConverter`.
>   Implementations may be may be registered directly with
>   `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` and `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` or
>   more likely annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` in which case they will
>   be auto-detected by both.

Here i'm intercepting all the returned `String`s and make them uppercase:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyResponseBodyAdvisor implements ResponseBodyAdvice<String> {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return returnType.getParameterType().equals(String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String beforeBodyWrite(String body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
        return body.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```