# How to modify HttpServletResponse to include some standard attributes in json using Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am writing a REST API application in spring boot. I want the signature of my json responses to be something like this:

Example:1

```
{
  "status": "Error"
  "httpcode": 500
  "dev_message": "ServerException"
  "user_message": "Oops..something went wrong with the app. Please try again."
  "response": {
    ...
   }
}
```

Example:2

```
{
  "status": "Success"
  "httpcode": 200
  "dev_message": "APICallSuccess"
  "user_message": "Successfully called API"
  "response": {
      "userid": "test",
      "age": 31 
       ...
      "country": "India"
   }
}
```

where `status, httpcode, dev_message` and `user_message` are dynamically updated at different stages of a request lifecycle. For example, the authorization filter should update the `httpstatus` field to `401` and `dev_message` to `AuthException` if API token is incorrect. On the other hand, controller should update the fields if a user is trying to access another user's data which he is not allowed and so on.

I have two part question here:

1. How to implement this in Spring MVC / Spring Boot? I know this involves `RequestHandlerInterceptor` and `Filters` but there is too much information and I am not able to narrow it down.
2. Is this the right approach of building my API? I want clients to really know what went wrong instead of just returning http status codes.

**EDIT 1:**
Lot of answers below are coming for a controller level. I am looking to handle this at a much higher execution level using filters. Suppose there is an authentication failure, then my request will not even reach the controller. In all such cases i want to implement the success and failure messages at one place so that it is clean and easy to understand.

Comment: easiest approach: make a base response class and return that?

Comment: HttpServeletResponse doesn't care for this.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are looking for this: Using Spring ResponseEntity to Manipulate the HTTP Response
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-entity

```
@GetMapping("/age")
ResponseEntity<String> age(
  @RequestParam("yearOfBirth") int yearOfBirth) {

    if (isInFuture(yearOfBirth)) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(
          "Year of birth cannot be in the future", 
          HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(
      "Your age is " + calculateAge(yearOfBirth), 
      HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

You can set error 404, 403 anything you want. Please let me know if it works

Answer (score -1):

I have used quite similar JSON response in both scenarios whether it is an error or response. You can give it a try, it may help you :)

**Error JSON:**

```
{
    "data": null,
    "message": "Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
    "infoType": "ERROR",
    "statusCode": 415,
    "errors": [
        "text/plain;charset=UTF-8 media type is not supported. Supported media types are application/octet-stream text/plain application/xml text/xml application/x-www-form-urlencoded application/*+xml multipart/form-data application/json application/*+json */"
    ]
}
```

**Response JSON:**

```
{
    "data": "{
        "id": 0,
        "name": null,
        "nestedObject": {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "",
            "url": "",
            // Other Details
        },
        "address": "address",
        "city": null,
        "country": "country"
    }",
    "message": "Your success message comes here",
    "infoType": "INFO",
    "statusCode": 200
}
```

I have created one abstract class which is Message. Two classes, Response and Error are there which are extending Message.

You can check out the code below:

**1. Used Enum For InfoType:**

```
public enum InfoType {
  ERROR, INFO, WARNING
}
```

**2. Abstract Class For Message:**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

public abstract class Message {

    private String message;

    private InfoType infoType;

    @JsonIgnore
    private HttpStatus status;

    private int statusCode;

    public Message(){

    }

    public Message(String message, InfoType infoType, HttpStatus status) {
        this.message = message;
        this.infoType = infoType;
        this.status = status;
        this.statusCode = status.value();
    }

    //Getters and Setters

}
```

**3. POJO Used For Response:**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;


@JsonPropertyOrder({ "data", "message", "infoType", "status", "statusCode"})
public class ResponseMessage extends Message{

    private Object data;

    private ResponseMessage() {
    }

    public ResponseMessage(Object data, String message, InfoType infoType, HttpStatus status) {
        super(message, infoType, status);
        this.data = data;
    }

    //Getters and Setters

}
```

**4. POJO Used For Error:**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

@JsonPropertyOrder({ "data", "message", "infoType", "status", "statusCode", "errors"})
public class ErrorMessage extends Message {

    private Object data;

    private List<String> errors;

    private ErrorMessage() {
    }

    public ErrorMessage(Object data, String message, InfoType infoType, HttpStatus status) {
        super(message, infoType, status);
        this.data = data;
    }

    public ErrorMessage(String message, InfoType infoType, HttpStatus status) {
        super(message, infoType, status);
        this.data = null;
    }

    public ErrorMessage(String message, InfoType infoType, HttpStatus status, List<String> errors) {
        super(message, infoType, status);
        this.errors = errors;
        this.data = null;
    }

    public ErrorMessage(String message, InfoType infoType, HttpStatus status, String error) {
        super(message, infoType, status);
        this.errors = Collections.singletonList(error);
        this.data = null;
    }

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

**5. Service Used For Warning/Error/Response:**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ResponseMessageService {

    @Autowired
    private ResponseMessages responseMessages;

    @Autowired
    private ErrorMessages errorMessages;

    public ResponseMessage generateResponseMessage(Object data, String messageKey, HttpStatus status) {
        return new ResponseMessage(data,responseMessages.getProperty(messageKey), InfoType.INFO, status);
    }

    public ResponseMessage generateWarningMessage(Object data,String messageKey, HttpStatus status) {
        return new ResponseMessage(data,responseMessages.getProperty(messageKey), InfoType.WARNING , status);
    }

    public ErrorMessage generateErrorMessage(Object data,String messageKey, HttpStatus status) {
        return new ErrorMessage(data,errorMessages.getProperty(messageKey), InfoType.ERROR , status);
    }
}
```

**6. Service To Read Errors From Property File:**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.List;

@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:errormessage.properties")
public class ErrorMessages {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public String getProperty(String property) {
        return env.getProperty(property);
    }
}
```

**7. Service To Read Messages From Property File:**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.List;

@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:responsemessage.properties")
public class ResponseMessages {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public String getProperty(String property) {
        return env.getProperty(property);
    }
}
```

**8. Finally Resource/API Class Utilising Above Things:**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.Map;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("user")
public class UserResource {

    @Autowired
    ResponseMessageService responseMessageService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity register(@RequestBody User user){
        if(success){
            return ResponseEntity.ok(responseMessageService.generateResponseMessage(null,"register.success",HttpStatus.OK));
        }else{
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(responseMessageService.generateErrorMessage(null,"register.fail",HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST));
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity login(@RequestBody User user){
        if(success){
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(responseMessageService.generateResponseMessage(data,"login.success",HttpStatus.OK));
        }else{
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(responseMessageService.generateResponseMessage(null, "login.fail",HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST));
        }
    }

}
```

9. For Handling Exceptions, I am using CustomExceptionHandler. In this handler also, I am using same error format.

   ```
   import org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException;
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
   import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
   import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
   import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
   import org.springframework.validation.BindException;
   import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
   import org.springframework.validation.ObjectError;
   import org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException;
   import org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
   import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
   import org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException;
   import org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException;
   import org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException;
   import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

   import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
   import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;


   @ControllerAdvice
   public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

       // 400

       @Override
       protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(final MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, final HttpHeaders headers, final HttpStatus status, final WebRequest request) {
           logger.info(ex.getClass().getName());
           //
           final List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();
           for (final FieldError error : ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors()) {
               errors.add(error.getField() + ": " + error.getDefaultMessage());
           }
           for (final ObjectError error : ex.getBindingResult().getGlobalErrors()) {
               errors.add(error.getObjectName() + ": " + error.getDefaultMessage());
           }

           final ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), InfoType.ERROR, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, errors);
           return handleExceptionInternal(ex, errorMessage, headers, errorMessage.getStatus(), request);
       }

       @Override
       protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleBindException(final BindException ex, final HttpHeaders headers, final HttpStatus status, final WebRequest request) {
           logger.info(ex.getClass().getName());
           //
           final List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();
           for (final FieldError error : ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors()) {
               errors.add(error.getField() + ": " + error.getDefaultMessage());
           }
           for (final ObjectError error : ex.getBindingResult().getGlobalErrors()) {
               errors.add(error.getObjectName() + ": " + error.getDefaultMessage());
           }

           final ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), InfoType.ERROR, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, errors);
           return handleExceptionInternal(ex, errorMessage, headers, errorMessage.getStatus(), request);
       }

       @Override
       protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleTypeMismatch(final TypeMismatchException ex, final HttpHeaders headers, final HttpStatus status, final WebRequest request) {
           logger.info(ex.getClass().getName());
           //
           final String error = ex.getValue() + " value for " + ex.getPropertyName() + " should be of type " + ex.getRequiredType();

           final ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), InfoType.ERROR, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, error);
           return new ResponseEntity<Object>(errorMessage, new HttpHeaders(), errorMessage.getStatus());
       }

       @Override
       protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMissingServletRequestPart(final MissingServletRequestPartException ex, final HttpHeaders headers, final HttpStatus status, final WebRequest request) {
           logger.info(ex.getClass().getName());
           //
           final String error = ex.getRequestPartName() + " part is missing";
           final ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), InfoType.ERROR, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, error);
           return new ResponseEntity<Object>(errorMessage, new HttpHeaders(), errorMessage.getStatus());
       }

       @Override
       protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMissingServletRequestParameter(final MissingServletRequestParameterException ex, final HttpHeaders headers, final HttpStatus status, final WebRequest request) {
           logger.info(ex.getClass().getName());
           //
           final String error = ex.getParameterName() + " parameter is missing";
           final ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), InfoType.ERROR, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, error);
           return new ResponseEntity<Object>(errorMessage, new HttpHeaders(), errorMessage.getStatus());
       }

       //

       @ExceptionHandler({ MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class })
       public ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentTypeMismatch(final MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException ex, final WebRequest request) {
           logger.info(ex.getClass().getName());
           //
           final String error = ex.getName() + " should be of type " + ex.getRequiredType().getName();
           final ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), InfoType.ERROR, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, error);
           return new ResponseEntity<Object>(errorMessage, new HttpHeaders(), errorMessage.getStatus());
       }

       @ExceptionHandler({ ConstraintViolationException.class })
       public ResponseEntity<Object> handleConstraintViolation(final ConstraintViolationException ex, final WebRequest request) {
           logger.info(ex.getClass().getName());
           //
           final List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();
           for (final ConstraintViolation<?> violation : ex.getConstraintViolations()) {
               errors.add(violation.getRootBeanClass().getName() + " " + violation.getPropertyPath() + ": " + violation.getMessage());
           }

           final ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), InfoType.ERROR, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, errors);
           return new ResponseEntity<Object>(errorMessage, new HttpHeaders(), errorMessage.getStatus());
       }

       // 404

       @Override
       protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleNoHandlerFoundException(final NoHandlerFoundException ex, final HttpHeaders headers, final HttpStatus status, final WebRequest request) {
           logger.info(ex.getClass().getName());
           //
           final String error = "No handler found for " + ex.getHttpMethod() + " " + ex.getRequestURL();

           final ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), InfoType.ERROR, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, error);
           return new ResponseEntity<Object>(errorMessage, new HttpHeaders(), errorMessage.getStatus());
       }

       // 405

       @Override
       protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported(final HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException ex, final HttpHeaders headers, final HttpStatus status, final WebRequest request) {
           logger.info(ex.getClass().getName());
           //
           final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
           builder.append(ex.getMethod());
           builder.append(" method is not supported for this request. Supported methods are ");
           ex.getSupportedHttpMethods().forEach(t -> builder.append(t + " "));

           final ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), InfoType.ERROR, HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, builder.toString());
           return new ResponseEntity<Object>(errorMessage, new HttpHeaders(), errorMessage.getStatus());
       }

       // 415

       @Override
       protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMediaTypeNotSupported(final HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException ex, final HttpHeaders headers, final HttpStatus status, final WebRequest request) {
           logger.info(ex.getClass().getName());
           //
           final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
           builder.append(ex.getContentType());
           builder.append(" media type is not supported. Supported media types are ");
           ex.getSupportedMediaTypes().forEach(t -> builder.append(t + " "));

           final ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), InfoType.ERROR, HttpStatus.UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE, builder.substring(0, builder.length() - 2));
           return new ResponseEntity<Object>(errorMessage, new HttpHeaders(), errorMessage.getStatus());
       }

       // 500

       @ExceptionHandler({ Exception.class })
       public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAll(final Exception ex, final WebRequest request) {
           logger.error("Error Occurred in Class " + ex.getClass().getName() + " ", ex);
           String message = ex.getMessage();
           String stackTrace = ex.fillInStackTrace().toString();

           final ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(message, InfoType.ERROR, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, stackTrace);
           return new ResponseEntity<Object>(errorMessage, new HttpHeaders(), errorMessage.getStatus());
       }

   }
   ```

Below are the references, I have used:

**1.** https://www.baeldung.com/global-error-handler-in-a-spring-rest-api
**2.** https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-security-rest/src/main/java/org/baeldung/web/CustomRestExceptionHandler.java

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. However, coming back to the question, I want to update the response from Filter chain filters and request/response interceptors. In that case the request will not even reach the controlleradvice and the code you have shared will not work. Therefore, I am looking for a way to update HttpServletResponse directly.

Comment: Also all your controllers now have the same return type. IMO this is a bad design all together. The controllers should return the data in a type safe manner and a filter should wrap that output into the standard ResponseEntity class.

Comment: I did not get your point about wrapping response in `ResponseEntity`. But I agree that it is not best solution what I have suggested you. I have also done a bit research and I have not found something which can help us. Few are suggesting to use [Map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38117932/8499307), but that also will be similar to my approach (Response will not be Type safe). Few are suggesting to use [ResponseBodyAdvice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34982802/8499307) but in that case data will be typesafe but what about the message.